# Javascript array of points how to curve fit?

Tags: javascript, curve-fitting

I have an array of points, each point consists of a x and y, the x is a timestamp, y is the actual data.

I have created a time series plot in Javascript and I would like to curve fit the data and draw the curve.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

My list of points:

```
    {fltX: 0, fltY: 55.932203389830505}
    {fltX: 1.8237082066869301, fltY: 55.932203389830505}
    {fltX: 3.6474164133738602, fltY: 55.932203389830505}
    {fltX: 5.47112462006079, fltY: 55.932203389830505}
    {fltX: 7.2948328267477205, fltY: 81.35593220338983}
```

The X co-ordinates have already been scaled to the X axis.  I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, however a good tutorial or guide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to find how to perform regression? Or how to draw a curve?

Comment: @kennytm, to be honest, I'm not sure, all I can tell you is that at the moment, I draw the poly line that is the result of the contents of the array and I would like to display the same data as a curve.

Comment: You want to draw something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIljM.png Which library you are using to draw the poly line?

Comment: @kennytm, yes, like that, I'm not using any library, just drawing on a canvas using moveTo and lineTo.

Comment: Ah. In this case, if you are doing it for a product, I suggest you just use [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-introduction) which handle how to draw a graph for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [genetic-js](http://subprotocol.com/system/genetic-js.html). To quote from the project page:

> From a plot of vertices, this genetic algorithm optimizes a continious
>   function to best fit the data (aka least squared error). Genetic.js
>   automatically runs the algorithm in the background with web workers so
>   that the UI experience isn't compromised.

An elaborate example is available [here](http://subprotocol.com/system/genetic-regression-curve.html).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to adapt this code or my vertices for use by the script....my array contains an array of X,Y points, but I can't quite see how to organise the data so that it is processed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

[Alglib.js](https://github.com/Pterodactylus/Alglib.js) seems like a good tool for what you need.

I used your points to fit a cubic spline in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webalizer12/jayu30t1/1/)

```
import {Alglib} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Pterodactylus/Alglib.js@master/Alglib-v1.1.0.js'

var f = function(a_n, x){
    return a_n[3]*Math.pow(x, 3)+a_n[2]*Math.pow(x, 2)+a_n[1]*Math.pow(x, 1)+a_n[0];
}

let data = [[0, 55.932203389830505],
[1.8237082066869301, 55.932203389830505],
[3.6474164133738602, 55.932203389830505],
[5.47112462006079, 55.932203389830505],
[7.2948328267477205, 81.35593220338983]]

var fn1 = function(a){
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        sum = sum + Math.pow(data[i][1] - f(a, data[i][0]), 2)
    }
    let sse = Math.sqrt(sum)
    return sse
}

let solver = new Alglib()
solver.add_function(fn1) //Add the first equation to the solver.
solver.promise.then(function(result) { 
    var x_guess = [1,1,1,1] //Guess the initial values of the solution.
    var s = solver.solve("min", x_guess) //Solve the equation
    let a=solver.get_results()
})
```

This produces an array of the polynomial coefficients:

```
a = [55.56900613862207, 4.812852278721678, -2.7300497536471293, 0.3492941022929858]
```

[image: Graph of fitted spline]

Answer (score -1):

An HTML5 canvas may tackle your need:

Javascript:

```
var hpms = {};

hpms.Graph = function( canvasId ) {
   this.MARGIN  = 30;
   this.canvas  = document.getElementById( canvasId );
   this.ctx     = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
   this.offsetY = this.canvas.height - this.MARGIN;
};

hpms.Graph.prototype.drawAxis = function( canvas ) {
   this.ctx.beginPath();
   this.ctx.moveTo( 0                , this.offsetY );
   this.ctx.lineTo( this.canvas.width, this.offsetY );
   this.ctx.moveTo( this.MARGIN, this.canvas.height );
   this.ctx.lineTo( this.MARGIN, 0 );

   var dx     = ( this.canvas.width - 2*this.MARGIN ) / 3;
   var yText  = this.offsetY + 3*this.MARGIN/4;

   var x      = this.MARGIN + dx;
   var legend = "1 year";
   this.ctx.moveTo( x, 0 );
   this.ctx.lineTo( x, this.offsetY + this.MARGIN/2 );
   x -= this.ctx.measureText( legend ).width/2;
   this.ctx.strokeText( legend, x, yText );

   x = this.MARGIN + 2*dx;
   this.ctx.moveTo( x, 0 );
   this.ctx.lineTo( x, this.offsetY + this.MARGIN/2 );
   legend = "2 years";
   x -= this.ctx.measureText( legend ).width/2;
   this.ctx.strokeText( legend, x, yText );

   x = this.MARGIN + 3*dx;
   this.ctx.moveTo( x, 0 );
   this.ctx.lineTo( x, this.offsetY + this.MARGIN/2 );
   legend = "3 years";
   x -= this.ctx.measureText( legend ).width/2;
   this.ctx.strokeText( legend, x, yText );

   var dy = 4;
   for( var y = 0; y < this.offsetY; y += 100 ) {
      this.ctx.moveTo( this.MARGIN/2    , this.offsetY - y );
      this.ctx.lineTo( this.canvas.width, this.offsetY - y );
      legend = "" + y;
      this.ctx.strokeText( legend, 0, this.offsetY - y + dy );
   }

   this.ctx.closePath();
   this.ctx.lineCap     = "round";
   this.ctx.lineWidth   = 1;
   this.ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
   this.ctx.stroke();
};

hpms.Graph.prototype.drawLinear = function( fn, color ) {
   this.ctx.beginPath();
   this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
   this.ctx.lineWidth   = 5;
   this.ctx.moveTo( this.MARGIN, this.offsetY - fn.b );
   var x = this.canvas.width - 2*this.MARGIN;
   var y = fn.a*x + fn.b;
   this.ctx.lineTo( this.MARGIN + x, this.offsetY - y );
   this.ctx.closePath();
   this.ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
   var g = new hpms.Graph("canvas");
   g.drawAxis  ();
   g.drawLinear({a:0.25, b:200}, "darkgray");
   g.drawLinear({a:0.80, b: 30}, "rgb(16,65,96)");
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        draw();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very familiar with Javascript and HTML 5 and I have already drawn a 2D graph containing the points, but what I want is to draw a curve of the points, not a saw tooth.